# $\lim_{(x, y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2)+y^2}{2x^2+2y^2}$

Tags: calculus

How can I determine $\lim_{(x, y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2)+y^2}{2x^2+2y^2}$?
I guess it is $1/2,$ but I can't use epsilon delta to prove it.
Since I substitute $\sin(X^2)$ into $x^2$ it would be less than $0.$ Can anyone tell me how to prove it? or does the limit just not exist? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can use MathJax here to improve your question. For example, lim_(x, y) to (0, 0) in your question can be presented as $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}$ by putting dollar signs($ \$ $) on both sides of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess was right:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)\atop(x,y)\ne(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2)+y^2}{2x^2+2y^2}=\frac12,$$
because we obviously have $\lim_{y\to0\atop y\ne0}\frac{\sin(0^2)+y^2}{0^2+y^2}=1,$ and
$$\lim_{(x, y)\to (0,0)\atop x\ne0}\frac{\sin(x^2)+y^2}{x^2+y^2}=1$$
because for $x\ne0,$
$$\begin{align}\left|\frac{\sin(x^2)+y^2}{x^2+y^2}-1\right|&=\left|\frac{\sin(x^2)-x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\\&\le\left|\frac{\sin(x^2)-x^2}{x^2}\right|\\&=\left|\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}-1\right|
\end{align}
$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{u\to0\atop u\ne0}\frac{\sin u}u&=
\lim_{u\to0\atop u\ne0}\frac{\sin u-0}{u-0}\\&
=\sin'0\\&=\cos0\\&=1.\end{align}
$$
Alternatively, if you prefer not to consider the two sublimits ($x=0,$ $x\ne0$) separately, you can rewrite this final argument as a Taylor approximation:
$$\sin u=u\left(1+\varepsilon(u)\right)\text{ where }\lim_{u\to0}\varepsilon(u)=0,$$
and replace $\sin(x^2)$ accordingly: for any $(x,y)\ne(0,0),$
$$\begin{align}\left|\frac{\sin(x^2)+y^2}{x^2+y^2}-1\right|&=\left|\frac{\sin(x^2)-x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\\&=\frac{x^2|\varepsilon(x^2)|}{x^2+y^2}\\&\le|\varepsilon(x^2)|.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: There is a little problem when $x=0.$

Comment: Thank you Ryszard! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

We have $${\sin(x^2)+y^2\over 2(x^2+y^2)}\le {x^2+y^2\over 2(x^2+y^2)}={1\over 2}$$
On the other hand
$${\sin(x^2)+y^2\over 2(x^2+y^2)}\ge {\sin(x^2)+\sin(y^2)\over 2(x^2+y^2)}\\
={\sin{x^2+y^2\over 2}\over x^2+y^2}\cos{x^2-y^2\over 2}$$
The first ratio tends to ${1\over 2},$ while the $\cos$-factor tends to $1.$
By the squeeze rule the limit is equal ${1\over 2}.$

Comment: Alternatively, $(\sin a)+b\ge\sin(a+b)$ for $a,b\in[0,\pi/4].$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks Anne. But the proof of the inequality requires trigonometry as well.

Comment: or "just" mean value theorem (btw: +1)